# Can't catch an <a> with .click in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why is it that I can't catch this `<a>`...

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="select2-choice select2-default" tabindex="-1">
   <span class="select2-chosen">select item</span>
   <abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr>
   <span class="select2-arrow">
      <b></b>
   </span>
</a>
```

... with this jQuery?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $( ".select2-choice" ).click(function() {
     alert( "Handler for .keydown() called." );
     });
});
```

I think this is the function that's generating the dropdown:

```
        createContainer: function () {
        var container = $(document.createElement("div")).attr({
            "class": "select2-container"
        }).html([
            "<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='return false;' class='select2-choice' tabindex='-1'>",
            "   <span class='select2-chosen'>&nbsp;</span><abbr class='select2-search-choice-close'></abbr>",
            "   <span class='select2-arrow'><b></b></span>",
            "</a>",
            "<input class='select2-focusser select2-offscreen' type='text'/>",
            "<div class='select2-drop select2-display-none'>",
            "   <div class='select2-search'>",
            "       <input type='text' autocomplete='off' autocorrect='off' autocapitalize='off' spellcheck='false' class='select2-input'/>",
            "   </div>",
            "   <ul class='select2-results'>",
            "   </ul>",
            "</div>"].join(""));
        return container;
    }
```

Actually, I'm trying to solve this issue [adding button on a select2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20977400/how-to-add-button-to-a-select2-dropdown-on-a-dynamic-table)  by adding the button when the user click the field, since my previous solutions aren't working.

I'm using Firefox 26.0 and Chrome Version 31.0.1650.63 m on a windows 8 machine, 64bit.

Does `<a href="javascript:void(0)" ... >` have something to do with it? Thank you for the help.

Comment: inline javascript is a bad decision atm. javascript void should stop it from doing the default action(like return false or e.preventDefault()). but as you can see it does not work properly anymore(in chrome it does nothing if another eventhandler is added to the element).

Comment: If you have jQuery version >= 1.7, consider using `.on('click'` instead of `.click` - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11878976/1311025

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/89QZ2/. In which browser are you experiencing the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Events triggered by dynamically generated element are not captured by event handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12829963/events-triggered-by-dynamically-generated-element-are-not-captured-by-event-hand)

Comment: and [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/203198/218196)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because $( ".select2-choice" ) did not match anything at the time of execution, so no event was bound. try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(document).on("click", ".select2-choice", function() { ... });
});
```

which adds a click event to the document that is filtered to the selector before executing the function.

Comment: hi @Hafthor thanks for the answer but its still not working, I tried binding it to another element e.g on text box with a class="qty" and it worked, maybe Im not really clicking the element with the class="select2-choice" but its the only <a></a> on that block T_T

Answer (score 3):

When you put `javascript:void(0)` in an `href`, in certain browsers, it will override whatever code you have associated with the `$(".select2-choice").click()`.

To fix this, you could change it to `<a href="#" class="select2-choice select2-default" tabindex="-1">`

[This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vZjPf/) actually works with both with the latest version of Chrome on Mac OSX, but I think it will break for some versions of IE

For your edit, I think that the problem is that when you make the event handler, there are no matching methods. You will want to use `.on("click",".select2-choice")` instead of `.click()`

Try this

```
$(document).on("ready",".select2-choice",function() {
     $( ".select2-choice" ).click(function() {
     alert( "Handler for .keydown() called." );
     });
});
```

Comment: Thank you @scrblnrd3 for your informative answer. :) but still I can make my alert box display whenever I click the anchor, actually the link was only generated by a javascript also on the run, does this affect its behavior? I know your code is correct but, my code doesnt seem to work :/

Comment: @melvnberd Did you remove the "javascript:void(0)" code from the href attribute?

Comment: @WilsonFreitas Yes I removed "javascript:void(0)" and replaced it with # as scrblnrd3

Comment: Could you post the code that generated that, as well as what browser you are using?

Comment: @scrblnrd3 yeah sure, ill just update my question above.

Comment: @scrblnrd3 yeah thank you for that :), I guess im just pointing out the wrong block here, but definitely your answers added new information on my brain. have a good day!