# Add a button to Select2 Dropdown list

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am using the lastest version of Select2. Want to add an Insert New button at the end of the dropdown list. I tried these two solutions I found online

Solution 1:

```
$(".select2-drop").append('<table width="100%"><tr><td class="row"><button class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-xs" onClick="modal()">Add new Item</button></div></td></tr></table>');
```

Solution 2

```
$("#itemId0").select2("container").find("div.select2-drop").append('<table width="100%"><tr><td class="row"><button class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-xs" onClick="modal()">Add new Item</button></div></td></tr></table>');
```

With Solution 1 nothing happens. With solution 2 I get the error message in the select 2 js file

> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'apply'
>   of undefined or null reference

Can anyone please help?

Here is my HTML

```
  <select id='itemId0' name='product[0][name]' class='form-control col-lg-5 itemSearch' >
                                <option></option>
                            </select>
```

AND the full select2 javascritp

```
           function productFormatResult(product) {
            if (product.loading) product.text;
            var html = "<table><tr>";
            html += "<td>";
            html += product.text;
            html += "</td></tr></table>";

            return html;
        }
        //  alert(html);
        function productFormatSelection(product) {
            var selected = "<input type='hidden' name='itemId' value='" + product.id + "'/>";
            return selected + product.text;
        }

        //$("#itemId0").select2();
        $("#itemId0").select2({

            ajax: {
                url: "@Url.Action("GetProducts", "Inventories")",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        q: params.term
                    };
                },
                processResults: function (data, params) {
                    return { results: data };
                },
                cache: true
            },
            escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
            minimumInputLength: 1,
            templateResult: productFormatResult,
            templateSelection: productFormatSelection,
            dropdownClass: 'bigdrop'
        });
       // $(".select2-drop").append('<table width="100%"><tr><td class="row"><button class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-xs" onClick="modal()">Add new Item</button></div></td></tr></table>');
        $("#itemId0").select2("container").find("div.select2-drop").append('<table width="100%"><tr><td class="row"><button class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-xs" onClick="modal()">Add new Item</button></div></td></tr></table>');
```

Comment: Please give full example, how does the html look? what javascript files are included in this instance?

Comment: have you figured out? I have exactly same problem getting the container of the select2

Comment: May be this post can be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20977400/how-to-add-button-to-a-select2-dropdown-on-a-dynamic-table

Answer (score 8):

check it

```
$('#select2').select2({
       placeholder: 'This is my placeholder',    
         language: {
             noResults: function() {
            return `<button style="width: 100%" type="button"
            class="btn btn-primary" 
            onClick='task()'>+ Add New Item</button>
            </li>`;
            }
         },
       
        escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
            return markup;
        }
    });
```

Update: (Explanation)

If you need to add button in select2 if no result found you just need to returnHTML Button code from **noResults** function and Add **escapeMarkup** function to render custom templates.

```
language: {
         noResults: function() {
        return `<button style="width: 100%" type="button"
        class="btn btn-primary" 
        onClick='task()'>+ Add New Item</button>
        </li>`;
        }
     },

    escapeMarkup: function (markup) {
        return markup;
    }
```

Try below example to see how it looks.

https://jsfiddle.net/Hamza_T/yshjqw85/32/

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example in [codepen](https://codepen.io/romeojathu/pen/jOMxgMa?editors=0010)

`html` is below

```
<select id="CustomSelect" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="volvo">BMW</option>
  <option value="saab">Jaquar</option>
  <option value="mercedes">RR</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

`CSS` is below

```
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

`Script` is below

```
$("#CustomSelect").select2({  
 width: '100%',
        allowClear: true,
        closeOnSelect: false
        
 }).on('select2:open', function () {
        let a = $(this).data('select2');
        if (!$('.select2-link').length) {
            a.$results.parents('.select2-results')
                .append('<div class="select2-link2 select2-close"><button>Close</button></div>')
                .on('click', function (b) {
                });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done with Select2's Adapters and Decorators (https://select2.org/advanced/default-adapters). However, personally I find this approach really heavy and to be honest I don't understand the documentation regarding this area.

What I personally do, is binding on the `select2:open`-event and appending a add-new-button container.

Here is an example:

```
// create new container
$('#select2').select2CreateNew("Create new");

// generic function
$.fn.select2CreateNew = function( text ) {

    // bind to "open"-event
    this.on( 'select2:open', function( e ) {
        let name = $( this ).attr( 'name' );
        let html = '<div class="s-add-new-container">' + text + '</div>';
        let $resultContainer = $( '[aria-controls="select2-' + name + '-results"]' )
            .closest( '.select2-dropdown' ).find( '.select2-results' );

        // avoid duplicates ~ append "create new" to result bottom
        if ( $resultContainer.find( '.s-add-new-container' ).length === 0 ) $resultContainer.append( html );
    } );
}
```

Customize the code or add some click-event handler for whenever the user clicks on the container.

For styling I'm using this CSS:

```
.s-add-new-container {
    padding: 7px;
    background: #f1f1f1;
    border-top: 1px solid #c7c7c7;
}

.select2-dropdown.select2-dropdown--below {
    border-radius: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #6b6b6b59;
}

.s-add-new-container:hover {
    background: #3db470;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```